# Jquery image path on server

Tags: php, jquery, html, iis

I'm trying to display an image that is located on the D drive of my server from an IIS website (located on C). When I go to localhost from the server, the image displays but when I do it eternally I get the below error message :

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file://hs01/2015Agency/Agency2015/Businesses/Bus_9440/Photos/1.JPG
```

Is there something I need to do in IIS? All I am doing is putting the path into a `<img>` using jquery - an example of this is below :

```
 $('.image2').html('<img src="' + image2 + '" width=100 height=100>');
```

Answer (score 0):

put the image in the server, for example `htdocs/images`is the path of your images, then use `src="/images/myimage.jpg"`.